# LocalDateTime and comparing

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to make a method that returns a boolean that compares the current month day and year to a supplied, saved month day and year. This is my code and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but all my supplied dates are coming up true. I think I have declared something wrong but I'm not sure.

```
public boolean isExpired(){
    boolean expired = true;

    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
    int month = today.getMonthValue();
    int year = today.getYear();
    int day = today.getDayOfMonth();

    if((this.expYear <= year) && (this.expMonth <= month) && (this.expDay <= day))
    {
        expired = false;
    }

    return expired;
}
```

Comment: So if expiry date is 2018-9-2 and today is 2019-7-1 you would consider it expired because of months comparison?

Comment: I would store expiry date as a LocalDate and do `return expiry.isAfter(today)`

Comment: First, I’d use `LocalDate` and then use the `isBefore`/`isAfter` support

Comment: You need to use nested ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `LocalDate` object `expDate` from your expiry date using `LocalDate.of(...)`, which you can do in the constructor of your class.

```
private LocalDate expDate;

MyClass(int expYear, int expMonth, int expDay) {
    expDate = LocalDate.of(expYear, expMonth, expDay);
```

There is no need to remember the fields expYear, expMonth and expDay separately as you can always retrieve them from the `expDate`.

Your isExpired method becomes:

```
return !LocalDate.now().isBefore(expDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the logic of isExpired() method like this

```
public boolean isExpired() {        
     LocalDate expiredDate = LocalDate.of(expYear, expMonth, expDay);       
     return LocalDate.now().isBefore(expiredDate);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isExpired(){
  boolean expired = false;

  LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
  int month = today.getMonthValue();
  int year = today.getYear();
  int day = today.getDayOfMonth();

  if((this.expYear < year) || (this.expYear == year && this.expMonth < month) || (this.expYear == year && this.expMonth == month && this.expDay <= day))
  {
    expired = true;
  }

  return expired;
}
```

Here! I have re-written your code for you and it will work fine now.

explanation:

- say if year is less then current year, then its expired for sure.
- if year is equal but month is less then current, then its expired for
  sure.
- if year and month are equal and the date is less or equal to current then it's expired for sure.
- if none of the above, then the product is still in a good condition